# i am getting error on execution of this shell program.. please tell me whats wrong/?

Tags: shell

my code is:

```sh
echo "Enter two numbers"
read a
c=20
echo $c
if[ $c -gt $a ];    then
    echo "This is block 1."
else
    echo "This is block 2"
fi
```

errors:

1. else unexpected
2. if [ not found

Comment: Add a space between the `if` and the bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell doesn't recognize `if` as a keyword in this context; it's looking for a command named `if[` and not finding it. You'd get the same error if you started a line with `ifx`.

Unlike most programming languages, the shell considers `if[` to be a single token. `[` is actually a (probably built-in) command, not a fundamental part of the shell's syntax (it's equivalent to the `test` commmand). `[` is as valid in a command name as a letter, digit, or underscore.

As Christian.K's comment says, the fix is to insert a space between the `if` and the `[` command:

```
if [ $c -gt $a ]; then
    echo "This is block 1."
else
    echo "This is block 2"
fi
```

(This applies to `sh` and shells derived from it, including `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`. `csh` and `tcsh` have different syntax rules.)